# Scrapy returns unicode - how to convert to a string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When I make a request to a url using scrapy shell, I get back something like this:

```
In [6]: sel.xpath("//div[@class='my_class']").extract()
 [u'<div class="my_class"><ul><li class="parent">\n<a href="/category/tractors-ride-on-mowers/">\n\u0422\u0420\u0410\u041a\u0422\u041e\u0420\u042b \u0438 \u0420\u0410\u0419\u0414\u0415\u0420\u042b</a>\n<div class="sub1"><div class="str"></div><ul><li><a href="/category/lawn-tractors/" class="">\u0421\u0430\u0434\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u04....
```

How can I convert that into a readable string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

once you print it (or write it into a file) it will be readable

```
>>> u = u'<div class="my_class"><ul><li class="parent">\n<a href="/category/tractors-ride-on-mowers/">\n\u0422\u0420\u0410\u041a\u0422\u041e\u0420\u042b \u0438 \u0420\u0410\u0419\u0414\u0415\u0420\u042b</a>\n<div class="sub1"><div class="str"></div><ul><li><a href="/category/lawn-tractors/" class="">\u0421\u0430\u0434\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440'
>>> print (u)
<div class="my_class"><ul><li class="parent">
<a href="/category/tractors-ride-on-mowers/">
ТРАКТОРЫ и РАЙДЕРЫ</a>
<div class="sub1"><div class="str"></div><ul><li><a href="/category/lawn-tractors/" class="">Садовые трактор
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- `sel.xpath("//div[@class='my_class']")` selects `div` elements.
- `sel.xpath("//div[@class='my_class']").extract()` gets you a string representation of the selected elements as HTML, as a list, and unicode content as [`\u` escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) if text nodes inside the selection contain Unicode code points.

You can alternatively ask for the string representation of that selected node using [XPath's `string()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string), directly:

- `sel.xpath("string(//div[@class='my_class'])").extract()`
- or use a common pattern of string-joining of `text()` nodes: `"".join(sel.xpath("//div[@class='my_class']//text()").extract())`

Note that `string()` will consider only the 1st element matching the expression as argument. From XPath 1.0 specs:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of **the node in the node-set that is first in document order**.

---

Example scrapy shell session:

```
$ scrapy shell
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f06700bc2d0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f06700b6f10>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: sel = scrapy.Selector(text=u'''<div class="my_class"><ul><li class="parent">\n<a href="/category/tractors-ride-on-mowers/">\n\u0422\u0420\u0410\u041a\u0422\u041e\u0420\u042b \u0438 \u0420\u0410\u0419\u0414\u0415\u0420\u042b</a>\n<div class="sub1"><div class="str"></div><ul><li><a href="/category/lawn-tractors/" class="">\u0421\u0430\u0434\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440''')

In [3]: print "".join(sel.xpath('//div[@class="my_class"]//text()').extract())


ТРАКТОРЫ и РАЙДЕРЫ
Садовые трактор

In [4]: for r in sel.xpath('string(//div[@class="my_class"])').extract():
    print r
   ...:     


ТРАКТОРЫ и РАЙДЕРЫ
Садовые трактор

In [5]:
```

Comment: Kindly share your input HTML

Comment: @jawanam , see edited answer with your truncated sample input